# Как обрезать/скрыть изображение при помощи css/html

Tags: css

Нужно вот это изображение обрезать только слева. Подскажите как это сделать? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `clip-path`, если тяжело рассчитывать координаты, вот сервис https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ в нём можно в графическом редакторе настроить обрезку и взять координаты.

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы увидеть текущий html-код и css, чтобы дать максимально точный ответ. Но возможно вашу проблему решит задание css-свойства `overflow: hidden;` к блоку с изображением кроссовка.

[Подробная информация на сайте MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)